# Linux: USB device power management

Tags: linux, usb, hard-drive, flash-drive

I have a USB Hard Drive

In **Windows**, i used to click the "Safely remove" icon, and the hdd *stopped spinning* and was unmounted.

Now, in **Linux**, unmounting doesn't poweroff the device, and it *proceeds spinning* when i remove it's cable. Is there a way to poweroff the HDD?

Additionally, I'd like to teach the KDE's "Device notifier" plasmoid to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like ***sudo sdparm --command=stop /dev/sd[x]***

Comment: <b>sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sd[x]</b> also makes the device enter sleep mode.